# ggplot add line to scatter

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have "observed data" which are classical [X, Y, Z] points. X, Y, Z are saved in vectors named X, Y, Z. (Typically 10-30 values.)

Then i have "result of model data" which is set of [X, Y] points creating a smooth line (= specially made regression line). Data are saved in Model_X and Model_Y vectors. (Around 1000 points to create extra smooth line.)

How to scatterplot "observed data" and then plot "result" line on top of this?

Code for scatterplotting "observed data" works well:

```
library("ggplot2")

Data_X = c(2,3,4,5,6,8,9,10,11,14)
Data_Y = c(3.25,3.66666666666667,1.83333333333333,2.4,2.5,2.375,2.16666666666667,2.8,2.18181818181818,1.85714285714286)
Data_Z = c(2,1,3,3,1,1,2,1,1,1)

Model1_X = c(1,1.13131313131313,1.26262626262626,1.39393939393939,1.52525252525253,1.65656565656566,1.78787878787879,1.91919191919192,2.05050505050505,2.18181818181818,2.31313131313131,2.44444444444444,2.57575757575758,2.70707070707071,2.83838383838384,2.96969696969697,3.1010101010101,3.23232323232323,3.36363636363636,3.4949494949495,3.62626262626263,3.75757575757576,3.88888888888889,4.02020202020202,4.15151515151515,4.28282828282828,4.41414141414141,4.54545454545455,4.67676767676768,4.80808080808081,4.93939393939394,5.07070707070707,5.2020202020202,5.33333333333333,5.46464646464647,5.5959595959596,5.72727272727273,5.85858585858586,5.98989898989899,6.12121212121212,6.25252525252525,6.38383838383838,6.51515151515152,6.64646464646465,6.77777777777778,6.90909090909091,7.04040404040404,7.17171717171717,7.3030303030303,7.43434343434344,7.56565656565657,7.6969696969697,7.82828282828283,7.95959595959596,8.09090909090909,8.22222222222222,8.35353535353535,8.48484848484848,8.61616161616162,8.74747474747475,8.87878787878788,9.01010101010101,9.14141414141414,9.27272727272727,9.4040404040404,9.53535353535354,9.66666666666667,9.7979797979798,9.92929292929293,10.0606060606061,10.1919191919192,10.3232323232323,10.4545454545455,10.5858585858586,10.7171717171717,10.8484848484849,10.979797979798,11.1111111111111,11.2424242424242,11.3737373737374,11.5050505050505,11.6363636363636,11.7676767676768,11.8989898989899,12.030303030303,12.1616161616162,12.2929292929293,12.4242424242424,12.5555555555556,12.6868686868687,12.8181818181818,12.949494949495,13.0808080808081,13.2121212121212,13.3434343434343,13.4747474747475,13.6060606060606,13.7373737373737,13.8686868686869,14)
Model1_Y = c(3.25,3.18555420097834,3.12926919689739,3.07941021181297,3.03473378038082,2.99431957725982,2.95746824042015,2.9236364484034,2.89239410255925,2.86339518366821,2.83635737247483,2.81104746070721,2.78727069071306,2.76486282326236,2.74368413932923,2.72361483829083,2.70455146117348,2.68640407763096,2.6690940496996,2.65255223653955,2.63671754016454,2.62153571758434,2.60695840309297,2.59294229779074,2.57944849328738,2.5664419038903,2.55389078712974,2.5417663366947,2.53004233509601,2.51869485588397,2.50770200720773,2.49704371004394,2.48670150564246,2.47665838770824,2.46689865561819,2.45740778560022,2.44817231731109,2.43917975366564,2.43041847210995,2.4218776458117,2.41354717347233,2.40541761665863,2.39748014371141,2.38972647942389,2.382148859795,2.37473999125844,2.36749301386891,2.36040146799541,2.35345926413012,2.34666065547108,2.34000021297974,2.33347280265142,2.32707356476813,2.32079789493082,2.31464142669197,2.30860001562977,2.30266972472342,2.29684681090454,2.29112771267366,2.28550903868246,2.27998755719325,2.27456018633652,2.26922398509527,2.26397614495246,2.25881398214421,2.25373493046685,2.24873653459143,2.24381644384331,2.23897240640893,2.23420226393503,2.22950394648906,2.22487546785239,2.22031492112025,2.21582047458498,2.21139036788103,2.2070229083721,2.20271646776243,2.19846947891591,2.19428043286793,2.1901478760162,2.18607040747793,2.18204667660161,2.17807538062293,2.17415526245479,2.17028510860243,2.16646374719532,2.16269004612806,2.15896291130317,2.15528128496922,2.15164414414803,2.14805049914555,2.14449939214096,2.14098989584917,2.13752111225228,2.13409217139578,2.13070223024546,2.12735047160163,2.12403610306702,2.12075835606543,2.11751648490801)

observedData <- data.frame("X" = as.factor(Data_X), "Y" = as.factor(Data_Y), "Z" = as.factor(Data_Z))

p <- ggplot(observedData, aes(Data_X, Data_Y))
p + geom_point(aes(colour = Data_Z)) + scale_colour_gradient(low = "green", high="red")
p + geom_line(aes(Model1_X, Model1_Y))  #<-- this replaces original scatterplot with line plot, but does not merge with it
```

How can I add line based on vectors Model_X and Model_Y? I've tried a lot of various ways, but couldn't move, always works only one of the plots.

Comment: You can call `geom_line` or `geom_path` and specify a new `data` parameter in it along with new `aes`thetics but add it to `p`. You didn't give actual or generated data, so it's difficult to actually assist you.

Comment: I see, i've updated the original post with specific data; i think the major problem is with specification of "model result data" parameter for geom_line call, but i cant figure out the way to put it in there

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally, thanks to both answers and comments, i've figured out "how to":

```
...
p <- ggplot(observedData, aes(Data_X, Data_Y))
p1 <- p + geom_point(aes(colour = Data_Z)) + 
    scale_colour_gradient(low = "green", high="red") + 
    geom_line(aes(Model1_X, Model1_Y))
p1
```

Thank you :-)

Answer (score 7):

```
library(ggplot2)

#Create a scatterplot using mtcars data with ggplot object p1 as the base layer
p1 <- ggplot(mtcars, aes(x = hp, y = mpg))

#Specify the color of points in the next layer
p1 <- p1 + geom_point(size = 2, aes(color=factor(am)))

#connect points with line
p2 <- p1 + geom_line()                           

#Adding a regression line
p3 <- p2 + geom_smooth(method = "lm", se = TRUE)  

p4 <- p3 + labs(x="Horsepower", y = "Miles per Gallon", title= "Linear Regression")

p4
```

[image]